# Can you find the function?

Tags: exponential-function

(Fair warning: I'm a computer engineer)

I was looking for a function $f$ that maps a value from $[0, 1]$ to $[\frac{1}{n}, n]$. So, $f(0) = \frac{1}{n}$, $f(1) = n$, $f(0.5) = 1$, $f(0.75) = \frac{n}{2}$ and so on...

I fired up Excell and it gives me [this simple graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYydB.png) (for $n = 4$ here)

Since it looks like a simple exponential curve, I theorize that I was looking for a function in the form $f(n) = (ax + b)^c$.

With a bit of trial and error, I found out that $$b = (\frac{1}{n})^{\frac{1}{c} }$$ to have that little shift up. Knowing that $n = (a + b)^c$, I know that [$$a = n^{\frac{1}{c}} - b.$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%3D%28a%2Bb%29%5Ec%20for%20a)

Plotting that with $c = 2$, gives me a [new graph with this estimation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93EUF.png).

Which looks good, but not curved enough. By increasing $c$, it gets closer and closer to the target curve. Remember that for now, I'm only comparing with the curves for $n = 4$. Well, of course, when [I tried with $n = 10$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0DYq.png), it diverges quite a bit.

In the end, I kind of find the solution to my problem (only for $n = 4$ which is my need), but I have to tend the power $c$ to infinity (which is less than convenient) and it feels pretty complicated for this simple curve.

What do I do wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: So $f(0) = \frac{1}{n}$, $f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = 1$, $f\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) = \frac{n}{2}$. Can you continue the sequence? I really don't understand the rule

Comment: Does this function works well to you?

$$f(x) = \left(16-\frac{8}{3n}-\frac{8n}{3}\right)x^3+\left(6+\frac{6}{n}-28\right)x^2 + \left(12-\frac{7n}{3}\right)x+ \frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: I put everything on [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zijvh3avix), first my target value on the table, then my estimation and finally your function.

Comment: Does

$$
f(x) =-2.66667 n x^3 - (2.66667 x^3)/n + 6. n x^2 + (6. x^2)/n - 2.33333 n x - (4.33333 x)/n + 1/n + 16 x^3 - 28 x^2 + 12 x
$$
work better?

Comment: @SewerKeeper, It does pretty well for $n=4$, but not for any other value.
I [added your function to the plotter](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lvt6sny1vb).